# Is it possible to render angular directive templates with isolated scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

I came across a strange behavior with an angular directive using an isolated scope. Apparently the template is resolved using the old scope (even if transcluded), not the new one.

This sounds a bit odd as it violates the 'isolation' of the directive's scope

**The html :**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    out prop = {{prop}}
    <div my-directive prop="'valueIN'">
      in prop = {{prop}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The js**

```
function MyController($scope) {
  $scope.prop = 'valueOUT';
}

angular.module('myApp',[]).directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: { prop: '=' }
  };
});
```

This outputs :

Angular 1.1

```
out prop = valueOUT
in prop = valueIN
```

Angular 1.2

```
out prop = valueOUT
in prop = valueOUT
```

which sounds weird to me...
Also got the same behavior with transcluding the template.

Is it possible to get the 1.1 behavior in 1.2 ?

Corresponding fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/4s1fxjmq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to recompile element in proper scope:

```
.directive('myDirective', ['$compile', function($compile) {
  return {
    scope: {
      prop: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      attr.$set('myDirective', null)
      $compile(element)(scope)
    }
  }
}])
```

Comment: This works but how do you do if you have code in your link initializing your scope (i.e. doing some computation on what to display in your template) ?

Comment: I'll settle with that for the moment (did it without isolated scope in the end to avoid the hacky re-wrap). This behavior is still weird to me...